# How can I reduce my if statements?

Tags: ruby

Going through Chris Pine's Learn To Program and working on the number to roman numeral conversion project.  The code below works, however it's pretty ugly w/ all those if (and end) statements.  However, when I use elsif the program doesn't respond (appears to freeze up).  Any thoughts would be helpful!

```
def calc input

roman_numeral = ''

while true
if input >= 1000 
  roman_numeral += 'M' * (input / 1000)
  input = input - (1000 * (input / 1000))

  if input <= 999 || input >= 500
  roman_numeral += 'D' * (input / 500)
  input = input - (500 * (input / 500))

  if input <= 499 || input >= 100
  roman_numeral += 'C' * (input / 100)
  input = input - (100 * (input / 100))

  if input <= 99 || input >= 50
  roman_numeral += 'L' * (input / 50)
  input = input - (50 * (input / 50))

  if input <= 49 || input >= 10
  roman_numeral += 'X' * (input / 10)
  input = input - (10 * (input / 10))

  if input <= 9 || input >= 5
  roman_numeral += 'V' * (input / 5)
  input = input - (5 * (input / 5))

  if input <= 4 || input >= 1
  roman_numeral += 'I' * (input / 1)
  input = input - (1 * (input / 1))

  puts roman_numeral

  break
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end
end


puts 'Give me a number, any number:'
input = gets.chomp.to_i
calc(input)
```

Comment: case input;
when 1..4 roman_numeral += 'I' * (input/1);...
when 5..9 roman_numeral += 'V' * (input/5);...

Answer (score 3):

It's convenient to use the method [Enumerable#find](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) with an array:

```
ARR = [[1000,'M'], [ 500,'D'], [100,'C'], [50,'L'], [10,'X'], [5,'V'], [1,'I']]

def which(input)
  ARR.find { |v,_| input >= v }
end

which(2)    #=> [1, "I"] 
which(7)    #=> [5, "V"] 
which(17)   #=> [10, "X"] 
which(77)   #=> [50, "L"] 
which(777)  #=> [500, "D"] 
which(7777) #=> [1000, "M"]
```

Assuming you are converting an integer to a roman numeral, consider making use of the method [Fixnum#divmod](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Fixnum.html#method-i-divmod). Suppose the integer were `2954` and you've already determined that there are two `"M"`'s and one `"D"` (so the beginning of your roman numeral string is `"MMD"`), and that `454` is left over. Then:

```
c, rem = 454.divmod(100)
    #=>[4, 54] 
c   #=> 4 
rem #=> 54
```

tells you there are four `"C"`'s with `54` left over.

Four `"C"`'s are written `"CD"` (not `"CCCC"`), however, so you may want to use a hash such as the following:

```
REP = {..., "C"=>["C", "CC", "CCC", "CD"], ...}
```

to convert the number of `"C"`'s to a roman numeral. Here you would append `REP["C"][4-1] #=> "CD"` to `"MMD"`: `"MMD" << "CD" #=> "MMDCD"`.

Comment: Cary - Thanks for the quick and detailed response.  At a high level it makes sense, however I think I've got a ways to go before I could properly implement your suggested approach.  While I've got you: any suggestions as far as resources for beginner rubyists?  As mentioned in my post, I'm going through Pragmatic's Programming for Beginners right now, which I'm enjoying.  Any other suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Here are some possibilities: [Core Ruby course at Ruby Learning](http://rubylearning.org/classes/), [Code School](https://www.codeschool.com/courses/try-ruby) and those listed at [iwantolearnruby](http://iwanttolearnruby.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The answer from Cary Swoveland is an excellent way to decrease your `if` block nesting.

His answer tells you which numeral comes next, but not how many (as in your code).  A natural way to tie it together is with a recursive function call:

```
class Romans
  def self.calc(input, acc = "")
    raise ArgumentError.new("Roman Numerals must be positve") if input < 0
    raise ArgumentError.new("Roman Numerals must be integers") if ! input.is_a? Integer

    return acc if input == 0 
    amount, numeral = which(input)
    acc += numeral
    input -= amount
    calc(input, acc)
  end

  @@ARR = [[1000,'M'], [ 500,'D'], [100,'C'], [50,'L'], [10,'X'], [5,'V'], [1,'I']]
  def self.which(input)
    @@ARR.find { |v,_| input >= v }
  end
end
```

In use:

```
pry(main)> (1..10).each{|i| puts "#{i}=> #{Romans.calc(i)}"}
1=> I
2=> II
3=> III
4=> IIII
5=> V
6=> VI
7=> VII
8=> VIII
9=> VIIII
10=> X

pry(main)> [Random.rand(1..100000)].each{|i| puts "#{i}=> #{Romans.calc(i)}"}
63124=> MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMCXXIIII
```

Be aware that ruby doesn't have TCO, and so will blow the stack with large enough numbers- but if you need the Roman numeral version of 8 million, you might want to make up some new letters.

Comment: Chris - Thanks for your reply.  As w/ Cary's response, it makes sense at a high level, however I think I have a bit further to go before I could make use of your approach.  Total noob here.  Regardless, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that uses string multiplication. For example: ('M' * 3) = 'MMM'

```
def to_roman(number)
  raise 'Must use positive numbers.' if number <= 0
  roman = ''

  roman << 'M' * (number        / 1000)
  roman << 'D' * (number % 1000 /  500)
  roman << 'C' * (number %  500 /  100)
  roman << 'L' * (number %  100 /   50)
  roman << 'X' * (number %   50 /   10)
  roman << 'V' * (number %   10 /    5)
  roman << 'I' * (number %    5 /    1)

  roman
end

puts to_roman(1234) # <-- test
```

Reference: Learn to Program 2nd by Chris Pine